# cocos2d-iphone-2.0-rc2.tar.gz is not Responding

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have installed the cocos2d-iphone-2.0-rc2.tar.gz but it not showing the list on xCode. Is there any one who can help me. 
My Xcode version is 4.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Run the template installer from the cocos2d-iphone-2.0-rc2 folder:

```
./install-templates.sh -f
```

[More details in this article](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/), including how to use cocos2d with ARC.